# How call getItem?

Tags: c++, auto

How can I call the below `getItem()` function?

```
template <typename item_t>
item_t getItem(const char* table_name, const int index) const {
  const char api_name[] = "getItem";
  typedef std::tuple<item_t> return_type;
  auto params = std::make_tuple(table_name, index);
  auto result = lua_.pcall<return_type>(api_name, params);
  return std::get<0>(result);
}
```

This does not work:

```
auto item = q.getItem("all_trades", 0);
```

Here is the full source code:

https://github.com/elelel/qluacpp

Comment: Define "not work". What happens?

Comment: return type is not deduced, you will need to pass type parameter explicitly: `auto res = getItem<int>(..` or `auto res getItem<std::string>(...`

Comment: I'm confused why you call `pcall` properly, but not `getItem`, seeing as how it's the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

The `getItem` template needs to know what `item_t` is when it’s called. In many cases, such as if you passed a value of the correct type as a parameter (as you would for a corresponding `setItem` function), the compiler can determine this by itself.

However, since none of the parameters seem related to `item_t` at all, the compiler cannot know what `item_t` should be, and therefore doesn’t know how to instantiate the template.

You either need to explicitly specify what the expected item type is when you call, as with `q.getItem<int>("all_trades", 0)`, or you need to find a way to tell the compiler what the expected type is some other way. I am not familiar enough with the Lua C++ API to be sure, but perhaps that would be the same as the `return_type` you use when calling `pcall`.